# Download file from server controller action using $.post method on client side

Tags: c#, razor, server, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using Asp.NET Core 5  (also use DevExtreme) and I have a grid with list of ids I want to press on a button and use this Id for download a file

I have a button as

```
   columns.Add().CellTemplate(new JS("editEntity"))
                                       .FormItem(f => f.Visible(false))
                                       .Width(130)
                                       .Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                                       .Caption("Download the file");
```

and JavaScript method as

```
function editEntity(container, options) {
        $('<div class="btn-dxButton show"></div>').dxButton({
            text: "Download the file",
            type: "default",
            onClick: function (e) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("Download", "ContName")',
                    { fileId: options.data.Id }, function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        alert(data.FileDownloadName);
                        //download(data.FileDownloadName,data)
                  });
            }
        }).appendTo(container);
    }
```

My controller action is

```
public FileResult Download(string Id)
{
     string FilePath = $"{Path}{fileId}.txt";

     var f = File(FilePath, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(FilePath));

     return f;
}
```

the grid look like that :

[image]

I have no idea what to do on the client side to download this file...
It is possible?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you make your download action a "get", a hyperlink to the download URL should suffice. Make sure you set the correct mime type. You will not need an "onclick" handler. Just insert a button styled anchor:

```
<a href="your download url" class="your button styled class... />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have Exception  as FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: {Path}.txt
But when I copy  {Path}.txt manual to my file explorer it is find this file